# Find the spherical angles

Tags: geometry, solid-geometry

I have a problem which I could not resolve. Consider a known single frequency plane wave coming from an  arbitrary $(\theta, \phi)$ direction  where $(\theta ,\phi)$ are the usual spherical coordinates. We know the time difference that are made by the wave with three given points below.

$B\left(\lambda, \frac{\pi}{2}, \frac{60\pi}{180}\right); $
$C\left(\lambda,\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{180\pi}{180}\right) ;$
$D\left(\lambda,\frac{\pi}{2},\frac{300\pi}{180}\right) ;$

I want to find the $\theta$ and $\phi$ of the wave in terms of the time difference. We know the speed of propagation as well so $\lambda$ which is wavelength is known .

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't see how the three given points give you any information about the location of $A$. You have three points, at given coordinates, and a fourth which is connected to all of them, but as far as I read the question might lie anywhere at all.

Comment: What do you mean by "We know the **time difference** that are made by the wave with three given points below. "?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually one would proceed as follows:
Let $N$ be the unit vector pointing in the direction 
where the plane wave comes from, let $u_1:=(C-B)/\|C-B\|$,
$u_2:=(D-B)/\|D-B\|$ and $u_3:=(u_1\times u_2)/\|u_1\times u_2\|$. 
Then $N=n_1 u_1+n_2 u_2+n_3  u_3$ for some real numbers $n_1,n_2,n_3$. 
We have $k_1:=N\cdot u_1=\frac{v(t_B-t_C)}{\|C-B\|}$ and 
$k_2:=N\cdot u_2=\frac{v(t_B-t_D)}{\|D-B\|}$, where $v$ is the speed. 
We set $s:=u_1\cdot u_2$ and can compute 
$$
n_1=\frac{k_1-s k_2}{1-s^2}\quad\text{and}\quad n_2=\frac{k_2-s k_1}{1-s^2}.
$$ 
Finally compute $n_3=\pm\sqrt{1-\|n_1u_1+n_2 u_2\|^2}$ and then you can convert the vector $N$ 
into spherical coordinates.

Evidently, there are conditions on $v$, $t_B-t_C$ and $t_D-t_C$ that guarantee that the data comes from a wave. The conditions can be resumed in the following  inequality on $k_1,k_2$:
$$
k_1^2+k_2^2-2s k_1 k_2+s^2\le 1.
$$
Note that if $u_1$ and $u_2$ are orthogonal, we are requiring that $k_1^2+k_2^2\le 1$. The inequality guarantees that $\|n_1u_1+n_2 u_2\|\le 1$.

Comment: $u_1,u_2,u_3$ are three linearly independent unit vectors, $k_1,k_2$ must satisfy the given inequality (this gives a vector $(k_1,k_2)$ of length lower than 1 if $u_1,u_2$ are orthogonal), the condition on $n_1,n_2$ is that $\|n_1u_1+n_2u_2\|\le 1$, which is satisfied if the inequality for $k_1,k_2$ holds.

Comment: I know of no special name for the inequality. It was just derived from the inequality $\|n_1 u_1+n_2 u_2\|\le 1$ which must hold, since $n_1 u_1+n_2u_2$ is the orthogonal projection of the unit vector $N$ on the plane generated by $u_1$ and $u_2$.

Comment: If you have three linearly independent time differences, you don't need to know the speed (if this comes from real world problems that can be an advantage). Moreover, if you place the four points at $(0,0,0), (1,0,0),(0,1,0),(0,0,1)$, then the computations are easier. If you have more than four points, I see no advantage, except for smaller errors, if you are dealing with real data.

Comment: $k_1$ is the (orthogonal) component of the unit vector $N$ we are searching in the $u_1$ direction. This means $N=k_1 u_1+R$ and $R$ is a vector which is orthogonal to $u_1$. So $k_1 u_1$ is the orthogonal projection of $N$ onto $u_1$. Similarly $k_2$ is the orthogonal component of $N$ in the $u_2$ direction. Since $u_1$ and $u_2$ are not orthogonal, we cannot recover directly the component $n_1 u_1+n_2 u_2$ of $N$ in the plane $u_1,u_2$ from these two components. This component  of $N$ is the vector in the plan such that $N=(n_1 u_1+n_2 u_2)+R_1$, where $R_1$ is orthogonal to the plane.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand much of probability and random matrices. You should try also to find a clearer formultaion to  the problem.

Comment: For example, where does X appears in the equation?

Answer (score 0):

We can think of this problem as just that of a plane moving through space.

The equation of plane moving in the direction of $\vec{k}$ with a speed $c=\omega/k$ is, $$ \vec{k} \cdot (\vec{x} - \vec{x}_0) + \omega t=0,$$

by plugging in the points which the plane passes through (with their corresponding times) we get a system of three equations with the three unknowns $(k_1,k_2,k_3)$. It is helpful to let $\vec{x}_0$ be the furthtest of the three points the wave passes through.